# after dispatching and updating redux store every useSelector renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

My Redux Store is Like this:

```
{
   data: {
      dashboards: {...},
      products: {...}
   },
   globalFilters: {
   ...
   }
}
```

problem is that when I dispatch **dashboards** data, fetching data from the backend and update store.
Saga:

```
export function* getDashboards() {
yield takeEvery(constants.GET_DASHBOARDS, function* generator() {
    try {
        const { data } = yield axios.get('/dashboards', {
            params
        });
        yield put(actions.setDashboards(data));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([fork(getDashboards)]);
}
```

reducer:

```
case constants.SET_DASHBOARDS:
    return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload.data
    };
default:
    return {
        ...state
    };
```

all useSelectors are triggered, including useSelectors(state => state.globalFilters) and rerendering all components, which are using any global data. how to solve this?

Comment: The reducer is providing a new value for the `data` slice. All the selectors that depends on them are going to be executed. If the selectors that depend on globalFilters are in child components of the components that use selectors that depend on anything in the `data`  slice they will also be re-executed (the parent rerender causes a re-registering of new useSelectors for globalFilters). redux toolkit `createSelectors` can help you with that by memoizing the returned values of the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your default reducer - it always creates a new state even if nothing ever changed.

Instead of

```js
    return {
        ...state
    };
```

do

```
   return state
```

Or, even better, use the official Redux Toolkit to write your reducers - it's the officially recommended standard to write reducers since 2019 and mostly prevents errors such as this, while reducing your code to 1/4.
See [why Redux Toolkit is how to write Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

Answer (score 0):

If your store looks something like this , then you wont face this problem

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        data: dataSlice.reducer,
        globalFilters: globalFilters.reducer
    },
})
```